# Authentication expires in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I want to log a user into an ASP.NET MVC site, and the session expires abnormally quickly, in minutes. I want the session to hold for days instead. Authentication is done using `System.Web.Security`:

```
FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
```

My `web.config` looks like this:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" 
             name=".ASPXAUTH" 
             timeout="86400" 
             slidingExpiration="true" 

             defaultUrl="Day/ListDays" 
             path="/"
             protection="All"
             requireSSL="false"
             cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" 
             domain=""
             enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
            <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                <user name="user" password="-" />
            </credentials>
        </forms>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"
       stateConnectionString="tcpip=loopback:42424"
       cookieless="false"
       timeout="300" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Please clarify:  Do you *want* it to expire in minutes, or you are trying to figure out *why* it expires in minutes?

Comment: clarified, I want to figure out why it expires so fast. Do you see a problem with the code?